# Put many Perl-Filters into ~/.vim

Tags: filetype-perl

I am pretty advanced in Vim. But one thing I am missing: how to put many Perl-Filters into Vim and run one of them over a selection. I was in former Times user of BBEdit, where I have set up many Perl-Filters, about 240 for Math, Text, Sorting, LaTeX, HTML ...

Would it possible to put them into my `~/.vim` and invoke them for a selection?

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

*EDIT*

Here an example. Problem copying from PDF-Files is the encoding of Umlauts. See also the comment in this filter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

# this filter is looking a bit strange. 
# but copying from a pdf file some text with 
# German Umlauts gives you double letters
# and not unicode letters. Don't know 
# how to explain it more precisely. 
# So the letter in the search and replace
# here are not the same. 
# And in Articles the hyphenation needs to 
# be removed

use warnings;
use strict;


while (<>) {
    s/- //g;
    s/’/'/g;
    s/„/"/g;
    s/“/"/g;
    s/­ //g;
    s/- (?!Euro)//ig;
    s/–/-/g;
    s/ü/ü/g;
    s/Ü/Ü/g;
    s/ö/ö/g;
    s/Ö/Ö/g;
    s/ß/ß/g;
    s/ä/ä/g;
    s/ç/ç/g;
    s/„/<em>„/g;
    s/“/“<\/em>/g;
    s/è/è/g;
    s/é/é/g;
    print;
}
```

Comment: I never used perl and I'm not sure what's the best way to convert your script but I think you might be interested by [this page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_embedded_Perl_interpreter).

Comment: I *know* i saw a similar Q about filters recently (this year). Im digging for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `!`.

Mark the lines you want to filter. Then hit `!`. The cursor will jump to the command line prefilled with

```
:'<,'>!
```

Then just type the filter you want to use. E.g.

```
:'<,'>!~/filters/fix-umlauts.pl
```

To filter the entire file use

```
:%!~/filters/fix-umlauts.pl
```

To only filter the current line, just hit `!!` and the command line is prefilled with

```
:.!
```

... just type your command:

```
:.!~/filters/fix-umlauts.pl
```

You could also work with text-objects (see `:help text-objects`). To filter the current paragraph just hit `!ip` and the command line is prefilled with something like (for a paragraph with 6 line):

```
:.,.+5!
```

(Means: First line of paragraph plus 5 following lines). Again type your command. Note that in this context the text-objects always select the entire line. E.g. `!aw` will filters the entire line of the selected word.

See `:help !`.

BTW: If the filters are in your shells `PATH`, you can just type the command name.

Comment: Thank you! I see how it works in theory! But mvim is refusing to replace the changed text. `:'<,'>!~/.vim/filters/text/pdf_to_text.pl` this is the script from above. `shell returned 2` and my selected text is replaced with something: `#!/usr/bin/perl: No such file or directory` Before I made a chmod 777 to the filter ... Hope this was clear enough?

Comment: Its working! I have a strange problem: only the half of the copied text-filters are seen by mvim. I dug into this problem, without any success. This is *not* due to the encoding, not to the permissions ... really strange. Thx Ralf for your help again!

Comment: Nice answer Ralf—I was going to add more about the `!` operator, but I'm not sure there's a good reason for me to add a new answer. Worth mentioning that `!` can be used as an operator (`!ap`) and not just in visual mode. `!!` does the current line. If the filters are in your shells `PATH`, you can just type the command name.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Updated. Thanks for the hint.